# Caml Query to return items created by logged in user

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, javascript, caml-query, caml, jsom

Using Javascript CSOM and want to return items created by logged in user, but the code below returns all items. Could someone advise?

```
var camlQuery = new SP.CamlQuery();

var specifier = "<Eq><FieldRef Name='Author'/><Value Type='Integer'><UserID/></Value></Eq>";

camlQuery.set_viewXml = "<View><Query><Where>" + specifier + "</Where></Query></View>"; 

this.collListItem3 = oList.getItems(camlQuery);
```

UPDATE

```
var oList = clientContext33.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle("MyAppList");

var camlQuery = new SP.CamlQuery();

camlQuery.set_viewXml = '<Where><Eq><FieldRef Name="Author" LookupId="TRUE" /><Value Type="Integer"><UserID/></Value></Eq></Where>'; 

this.collListItem3 = oList.getItems(camlQuery);

clientContext33.load(collListItem3,'Include(Title,ID,App_x003a_Link,App)');

clientContext33.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryAppSucceeded), Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryAppFailed));        

}
```

but still shows all items

Comment: You still need to have <View><Query>YourCAML</Query></View>

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
 var context = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    var list = context.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle("ListName");
    var cQuery = new SP.CamlQuery();
    var camlXML = "<View><Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='Author' LookupId='True'/><Value Type='Lookup'>" + _spPageContextInfo.userId + "</Value></Eq></Where></Query></View>";
    cQuery.set_viewXml(camlXML);
    var listitems = list.getItems(cQuery);
    context.load(listitems);
    context.executeQueryAsync(function() {
            var enumerator = listitems.getEnumerator();
            while (enumerator.moveNext()) {
                var item = enumerator.get_current().get_fieldValues();
                console.log(item);
            }
        },
        function(s, a) {
            console.error(a.get_message());
        });
```

Though it works, I prefer the query provided by Yayati to use `<UserID/>` in caml Query instead of `_spPageContextInfo.userId` , as this userid is only available on SharePoint application pages in browser. however you can use this query to get items of a specific user, instead of current user by passing the userid.

Comment: Although this (currently accepted) answer should function as well, I prefer the answer of Yayati (that means, using the <UserID/> CAML tag in the comparision, instead of relying the _spPageContextInfo variable). The _spPageContextInfo might not exist on the page, depending in which context you use your script.

Comment: Yeah, I prefer the same

Answer (score 7):

The Author column is of `LookUp` Type. Here is the complete list.

```
var ctx = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
var list = ctx.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle("Vacation Replacement");
var query = new SP.CamlQuery();
var specifier = "<Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='Author' LookupId='True'/><Value Type='Lookup'><UserID/></Value></Eq></Where>";
query.set_viewXml("<View><Query>"+specifier+"</Query></View>");
var collListItems = list.getItems(query);
ctx.load(collListItems);
ctx.executeQueryAsync(
    function(){
        var enumerator = collListItems.getEnumerator();
        while(enumerator.moveNext()){
            var item = enumerator.get_current();
            alert("ID : " + item.get_id());
        }
    },
    function(sender,args){
        alert("Request Failed."+args.get_message() + "\n" + args.get_stackTrace());
    }
);
```

Answer (score 2):

Create a custom view of the list and select radio button

Show items only when the following is true:
created by is equal to type   [Me]

save the list.
[image]

```
 function getItemsFromView()
{
var context = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    var list = context.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('ListName');
    var view = list.get_views().getByTitle('CustomViewName');
    context.load(view);

    context.executeQueryAsync(
        function(sender, args) {OnSuccess("<View><Query>" + view.get_viewQuery() + "</Query></View>")},
        function(sender, args) {alert("error: " + args.get_message());}
    );
}
```

It will fetch your records of logged in user only.

Its Done!!

Answer (score 2):

To get current user Id

```
clientContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
 var user=clientContext.get_web().get_currentUser();
 clientContext.load(user);
clientContext.executeQueryAsync(function(){
 var userId=user.get_id();

 var query="<Where><Eq>"+
    "<FieldRef Name="Author" LookupId="TRUE" />"+
     "<Value Type="Integer">" +userId + "</Value></Eq></Where>";

},failCallbackMethod);
```

This [link](http://www.ashokraja.me/tips/How-to-use-User-Name-User-Id-Logged-in-User-Id-in-SharePoint-CAML-Query) might help you

Comment: here author is using client object model so "SPContext.Current.Web.CurrentUser.ID" will not work

Comment: Oh! will update the answer

Comment: And one could switch +userid+ with <UserID/> for current user. The OP didn't add LookupId="TRUE" in his CAML

Comment: Thanks for help.
I'm using camlQuery.set_viewXml  and trying to use my existing code but i still see all items, see update question in OP pls.